# hiding stuff in the form of sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have been working with Sharepoint for a while and I find it difficult to make it so that the user cannot change the column, but the option to do so is still in the form.

So my question is - how can I hide the question in the form?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom form with PowerApps for example.

Another option you have is the modification of the SPFields in the list.

Each field has 3 properties that manage if the field will be shown in the corresponding form that are generated by SharePoint.

ShowInDisplayForm 
Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the field is displayed in the form for displaying list items.

ShowInEditForm 
Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the field is displayed in the form that is used to edit list items.

ShowInListSettings 
Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the field is displayed in the page for customizing list settings.

ShowInNewForm 
Gets or sets a Boolean value that specifies whether the field is displayed in the form that is used to create list items.

I hope this helps.
Heiko

Comment: Iam lookign at those ideas SPFields looks the easiest. i can use powerapp and i know how to make it hidden but then i get problems with the save and cancel buttons